# How to show a component and a variable within the true case in a ternary in React/jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to do a ternary inside of a div that renders a component I’ve built and a variable vs. a button, but my syntax is throwing an error. Does anyone know how I can alter this so that it does what I want?

```
<div>
{thing ? <WorkListBadge /> item.resource : <button> Click Me 
</button> } 
</div>
```

It’s erroring on the `<WorkListBadge />` part with
    `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected :`

I tried a bunch of different jsx variations with no luck. This is within a jsx file.

I'm new to React and could totally be going about this the wrong way as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only render a single entity in a ternary. Wrap both of your elements in a `<div>` to combine them into a single item. Remember to add curly braces for `item.resource`

```
 <div>
{thing ? <div><WorkListBadge /> {item.resource}</div> : <button> Click Me 
</button> } 
</div>
```